# Can't access the home page of xampp with domain

Tags: php, dns, xampp

I have a domain resolving to the IP of remote server, but I can't access any page of xampp I have deployed.

However, when I try to ping my domain `paranani.com`, the ip was accessible.
At least I supposed there to be a phpmyadmin or dashboard page? In the browser it just said "the site can't be reached".

In my httpd-vhost.conf file I have:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/qbank" ServerName paranani.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do?

Comment: have you set up a virtual host in your host file?

Comment: work for me, try again

Comment: yes,in my httpd-vhost.conf file like this:`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/qbank"
    ServerName paranani.com
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: _“the ip was accessible”_ - that means the machine is basically reachable, it says nothing about whether the web server on it is even running …